# Shell Script With Proper Permissions Gets "Not Found" When Attempting to Run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, docker

I have a weird situation going on.  I have created an Ubuntu-based Docker container and copied in a bash shell script that will be used in that container.  I can go into the CLI for the container and see the script file, verify that the permissions are correct (755) and can view the contents of the script file.  However, when I attempt to execute the script (using the fully qualified path), I get a "not found" error.  Note that I don't get a "permission denied" error, I get a "not found" error.

I'm no rookie when it comes to Linux/UNIX, so this should be an easy issue to resolve that usually involves user error.  I've never seen a situation where I can have the correct permissions and view the contents of a script file but have the system tell me that it's not found when trying to execute it.  I actually create three different containers that do the same, two of them fail with this error and the third is fine.  They are all created in the same manner.

This issue occurs with both sh and bash.  Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: It would be better if we knew the *exact* script, commands, error message. My point is [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) is way better than waving hands. That said, *maybe* [the loader specified in the shebang line is missing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11008/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Unfortunately, I cannot share the script as it would violate NDA with my employer.  The shebang is there and it is correct.  I have tried both /bin/bash and /bin/sh, both of which exist in the container.

Comment: So you say, you can't execute `/path/to/script.sh`, correct? Can you run `cat /path/to/script.sh?`

Comment: Another thing: even if the user has permissions to run the script, does the user have permissions to view the contents of all directories in the path?

Comment: It would be very helpful to have the Dockerfile added, as well as the results of `id` and the ownership of the file too (`ls -la`). How are the containers that behave differently created?

Comment: @TheQueenIsDead As mentioned previously, I can't share as it would violate NDA.  The ownership of everything is root/root and running as root when going into the cli.  All three containers are created in the same way, from the same machine and with the same command.  The only thing different is they have different tags.

Comment: @Malik Every directory down the path is accessible.